# setattr() not assigning value to class member

Tags: python, reflection, setattr

I'm trying to set up a simple test example of `setattr()` in Python, but it fails to assign a new value to the member.

```
class Foo(object):
    __bar = 0
    def modify_bar(self):
        print(self.__bar)
        setattr(self, "__bar", 1)
        print(self.__bar)
```

Here I tried variable assignment with `setattr(self, "bar", 1)`, but was unsuccessful:

```
>>> foo = Foo()
>>> foo.modify_bar()
0
0
```

Can someone explain what is happening under the hood. I'm new to python, so please forgive my elementary question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A leading double underscore invokes python [name-mangling](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables).

So:

```
class Foo(object):
    __bar = 0  # actually `_Foo__bar`
    def modify_bar(self):
        print(self.__bar)  # actually self._Foo__bar
        setattr(self, "__bar", 1)
        print(self.__bar)  # actually self._Foo__bar
```

Name mangling *only* applies to identifiers, not strings, which is why the `__bar` in the `setattr` function call is unaffected.

```
class Foo(object):
    _bar = 0
    def modify_bar(self):
        print(self._bar)
        setattr(self, "_bar", 1)
        print(self._bar)
```

should work as expected.

Leading double underscores are generally not used very frequently in most python code (because their use is typically discouraged).  There are a few valid use-cases (mainly to avoid name clashes when subclassing), but those are rare enough that name mangling is generally avoided in the wild.